# Combine two DataFrames column wise in Pandas

Tags: dataset, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 Dataframes as shown and I want a new DataFrame where the 1st column is the 1st column of the 1st DataFrame and 2nd column from the 1st column of the 2nd DataFrame. I have tried pivot table etc but have no luck.

```
    A   B
0   1   2
1   3   67
2   4   54
```

```
    C   D
0   0   19
1   23  6
2   55  5
```

I need a new DataFrame like this.

```
    A   C   B   D
0   1   0   2   19
1   3   23  67  6
2   4   55  54  5
```

Answer (score 3):

Use pandas.DataFrame.reindex()

```
df = pd.concat((df1, df2), axis=1)

#reorder columns
column_names=["A","C","B","D"]
df = df.reindex(columns=column_names)
```

Comment: why is this so flaming unintuitive? I've been working in python for 5+ years and literally have to look this up weekly beause pandas can't keep consistent syntax with similar functions and operate like df.concat(df2, axis=1)???

Answer (score 0):

I'd do `pandas.concat` and then reorder my columns.
Something like this:

```
# Concatenate along axis 1
df_new = pd.concat((df1, df2), axis=1)

# New order of columns, interleaved in this case
new_cols_order = np.array(list(zip(df1.columns, df2.columns))).flatten()

# Reorder columns
df_new = df_new[new_cols_order]
```

Edit: I noticed the answer from Dee, which came after mine despite not involving any novelty at all. Also, my solution let's you achieve your goal without specifying the column order manually.